# Ignore a Type during Deserialization with SharpSerializer

Tags: c#, deserialization, sharpserializer

Is it possible to ignore a certain type if a exception is thrown during Deserialization?
I can add Properties to ignore like so:

```
var setting = new SharpSerializerXmlSettings();
setting.AdvancedSettings.PropertiesToIgnore.Add(type, "myPropToIgnore");
sharpSerializer = new SharpSerializer(setting);
```

But the sourcetype is not known in my current Runtime. So I can not add it.
What can I do?